# Using Input in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to style certain contains on a page based on whether a form field contains a value when submitted.  In my blade template I've got the following code:

```
@if (Input::has('field'))
    <li class="option active">
@else
    <li class="option">
@endif
```

However, `Input::has()` seems to always return false.  I know that the data is there however because I can populate the form field itself like this:

```
{{Form::text('field', Input::old('field'))}}
```

The same `Input::has('field')` call will return true in the post method on my controller however.  Does this mean that the `has` method doesn't look at the data in the `old` array?  If not, what would be a good alternative to my approach?

Comment: The `Input` class is related to the _user input submitted in a form_. So, it will not work as you expect.

Comment: I revised my question.  After a form is submitted, the page is reloaded with and contains the user submitted data in `Input::old()`

Answer (score 0):

Just use Input::old() - which contains the data. Input::has() is for the controller using your post data.

This should work:

```
@if (Input::old('field'))
    <li class="option active">
@else
    <li class="option">
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

`Input::has()` does not take session-bound data (aka old input) into consideration, so it will not be useful for checking for a value in that way.

How about using CSS by itself? You can target element attributes in CSS -- in this case, the `value` attribute.

```
/* Target all inputs. */
input { color: #444; }

/* Target all inputs that have a "value" attribute defined (even if empty) */
input[value] { color: #bada55; }
```

Note that this will only work if the `value` attribute is not that entirely. If it is defined but empty, the new color will still take precedence. So this solution may or may not work, entirely dependent on how your HTML is generated. Food for thought.